# Java Exception in thread main - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point, classnotfoundexception

I'm working with another system library in Eclipse. One time, the library got somehow removed and eclipse showed a red "!" next to the projects folder icon. I re-imported the library, but there is still the red "!". Once I try to compile and run a program, it gives me a "ClassNotFoundException".

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

My java file:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

}
```

I don't see any mistakes in my source code. What is going on?

Comment: there is a view called problems view and you can see the errors in there, mostly it is a classpath related error

Comment: check the classpath, you can find the error there

Comment: Where your `.class` files are being saved? Have you set the classpath ?

Comment: In eclipse  rightclick on project-->properties-->java build path-->remove the old library and add new one

Comment: @Pragnani make that an answer, you deserve the points

Comment: @MrD Thanks, I have posted the answer as you suggested.

Comment: @felix fritz please mark the answer as accepted so we can close this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting Comments as Answer

> In eclipse rightclick on project-->properties-->java build path-->remove the old library and add new one

Comment: Thanks for making it official ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go the the Package Explorer, scroll up and right click on the name of your project (that must appear with a red cross) and then select refresh.

I was sorted out using that method. I hope it will help you.

Comment: This was answered 6 months ago already, but thanks. (how did you even find this question?)